# share requests between servers with nodejs socket io + express+ react client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to write a following application:
I have 2 servers on 2 different machines. Client can connect to server A, send some message, then connect also to server B, send again messages, and he will see messages received on both servers on each client window. It means that when server A or B receives messages, they should send it to the second server and the second server should emit this message to client. I tried the following code, on localhost different ports, same code on both servers, but it seems that "socket_other_server.on(serv_message)" never happened.
Any suggestions please?

```
const app = require('express')()
const http = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(http)

var client = require('socket.io-client');
var socket_other_server = client.connect('http://localhost:4002', { reconnect: true });


io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('message', ({ name, message }) => {
    io.emit('message', { name, message })
    console.log("Message from client broadcasted: " + message);
    console.log("Sending message to 8002 server: " + message);
    socket_other_server.emit('serv_message', { name, message });
});

  })

  socket_other_server.on('connect', function () {
    console.log("CONNECTED")
    socket_other_server.on('serv_message',  ({ name, message }) =>{
      console.log('RECEIVED MESSAGE FROM SERVER 8002 '+ message);
      io.emit('message', { name, message });

  });
  console.log('Connected to server 4002!');
});

http.listen(4003, function() {
  console.log('listening on port 4003')
})
```

Comment: if it was not clear, the: console.log('RECEIVED MESSAGE FROM SERVER 8002 '+ message); line never printed

Answer (score 0):

Since it is 2 applications running on different machines (simulated by using different ports in your case), Server A won't know what's happening on Server B and vice versa. You should use a database of some sort, where both servers have access to. It serves as some sort of bridge between the two.

The concept is similar to session storage. If you use load balancers for your application, how does one server knows if the client is logged in if the login request is made on the other server in your pool of servers?

The server can check the session storage shared by all of them, so it can know that the user is already logged in.